# Terminology for lower numeric bound - analogous to "capped"

Tags: terminology

What programming term should be used for describing putting a *lower* range on a number?

We use "capped" to refer to a limit on the *upper* value of a range.

What is the analogous term for limiting the lower end of the range?

Ideally the answer would be a single-word verb (in the past tense), ie

> The monthly fees have been X to $10

And mean "software changes have been added to the system, perhaps a database trigger/constraint or application code, to ensure the minimum monthly fees is never less than $10"

Comment: Infimum, however, this is the wrong site to ask this.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about maths terminology.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic. Why not http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: Maybe English Language & Usage stackexchange at http://english.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: @AdrianPanasiuk I asked it there already and got decided on "floored", but I wanted a programmer's perspective.

Comment: @DannyVarod I hear you, however I wanted a word that basically means "some code has been added to the system that ensures the value doesn't go below X", and I wanted a programmer's word for it

Comment: In that case, minimum or infimum **constraint**.

Comment: @DannyVarod thanks, but they are nouns. see edited question for refinement if definition.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a direct equivalent term. A suitable substitute would be **bounded below by**. Indeed, in the case where you have both a lower and an upper limit, saying **bounded by X and Y** would be a clear and concise way of expressing it.

Alternatively you could just refer to the **lower limit** and **upper limit** of the range.

Comment: I'm looking for a single-word verb (in the past tense), like "capped" is. It's still a reasonable answer though

Comment: @Bohemian As I said, *I don't think there is a direct equivalent term*. But I'm cautious about saying there definitely isn't one in case someone comes up with it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
The monthly fees start at $10
```

?

Comment: It's not a past tense verb. See edited question for clarification of what I'm after.

Comment: @Bohemian `Ideally the answer would be a single-word verb (in the past tense)` *Ideally* (not necessarily:)